# dynamically created buttons are not displaying

Tags: android

I am adding Buttons,buttons on table row dynamically by following code.

```
tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tl);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "option size " + optionList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                while (i < optionList.size()) {

                    tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

                    option = optionList.get(i);
                    Log.d("TAG", option.getPaymentReason());
                    button = new Button(getActivity());
                    button.setId(option.getId());//set id
                    button.setText(option.getPaymentReason());//set button title
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(option.getBgColor()));//set btn background
                    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(option.getTextColor()));//set text color
                    button.setLayoutParams(params);


                    tableRow.addView(button);

                    i++;
                }

but buttons are not creating.


Log.d("TAG", option.getPaymentReason());
```

this log is showing correct output.I have traied with sample text (test),then it adds buttons (by following code)

```
tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tl);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "option size " + optionList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        while (i < optionList.size()) {
tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

            option = optionList.get(i);
            Log.d("TAG", option.getPaymentReason());
            button = new Button(getActivity());
            button.setId(option.getId());//set id
            button.setText("test");//set button title
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(option.getBgColor()));//set btn background
            button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(option.getTextColor()));//set text color
            button.setLayoutParams(params);


            tableRow.addView(button);

            i++;
        }
```

Please help

Comment: please post your params. which LayoutParams you use for  make params object

Comment: params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Answer (score 1):

It's seems your layoutparams issues change

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and work's fine.